# TypeScript: import an ES2015 module without type definitions

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a working ES2015 project, which I would like to migrate to TypeScript.

In my solution I am using ES2015 imports to import 3rd-pary modules (installed via npm) like this:

```
import {ClassXY} from 'moduleXY'
```

After setting up TypeScript in my project, the TypeScript compiler reports the following error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find module 'moduleXY'
```

How can I get the above ES2015 import statement working in TypeScript?

I am looking for a solution other than installing the corresponding `.d.ts` declarations via `typings`... let's assume the module `moduleXY` is a library that does not distribute its own `.d.ts` declarations and there are no declarations available on DefinitelyTyped (or the declarations are outdated).

Must I create a stub for the type definitions of module `moduleXY`? How would I do that with minimal effort?

Answer (score 3):

if there are no typings for a module then you can just 
`require` it like a regular commonjs module

```
declare require:any;

const moduleXY:{
    classXY:any
} = require("moduleXY");
```

in a .ts file and make sure that file is included with your source in the Typescript compiler. you don't need to fully declare the module, and you will still benefit in places where you start adding types moving forward.

Comment: If you're using a module loader/bundler, will this do anything to ensure that the given module actually gets loaded?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior unfortunately not, but if you are using WebPack and the ts-loader you can use require instead of import to load the module

Comment: This seems not to work... I get a compile error: `'{' expected` ... so I think the statement to declare should be `declare module 'react-redux' {};` ... this gets rid of the initial compile error (`Cannot find module ...`) ... but TS still can't resolve the `import {ClassXY} from 'moduleXY';` ... the resulting error is now `Module "moduleXY" has no exported member 'ClassXY'`

Comment: @jbandi thank you for pointing that out, unfortunately there is a naming conflict between Typescript Modules and ES6 Modules that wont let you pull in ES6 modules suing `import`but you can substitute `require` instead to import your js code if you are using WebPack.

Comment: This makes a migration from ES2015 to TS much more intrusive than previously a migration from ES5 to TS ... in my understanding TS is not a "superset of ES2015" if I have to change all my import statements ...

Comment: @jbandi good point, looks like you are not the only one experiencing this issue and a fix is already being worked on. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7542

Comment: What does it mean by "make sure that file is included with your source in the Typescript compiler"? Is it in `webpack.config.js`? Could you please give a code snippet of the config file which includes the `.ts` file?